# Forward Declaration for a Struct in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, forward-declaration

following is my header file

```
#ifndef _ASYNCHRONOUSCLASS_H
#define _ASYNCHRONOUSCLASS_H
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

typedef int (*functionCall)(void *);
typedef void * voidPtr;

class  AsynchronousFunction{    
//int returnVal; 
//functionCall fCall;
//voidPtr param;
//HANDLE m_hEvent;

struct pImpl;
pImpl* m_pImpl;

public:
    AsynchronousFunction(functionCall fCall, voidPtr param);
    ~AsynchronousFunction();
    void functionExecuter();
    int result();

protected:
private:    
};
#endif
```

In the cpp file I want to implement the struct which contains following details.

```
*//int returnVal;* 
*//functionCall fCall;*
*//voidPtr param;*
*//HANDLE m_hEvent;*
```

How can I implement this ? What would be suitable, forward declaration or pointer implementation ?

Comment: I would use forward declaration. Could you please make `pointer implementation` clear?

Comment: In pointer to implementation you can define a pointer of some type, but it's implementation in separate file. But I'm not sure how implement forward declaration or pointer to implementation. Could you please explain how do this using forward declaration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single translation unit you will need to provide the definition of the type. It will look like:

```
struct AsynchronousFunction::Impl {
   // members and functions...
};
```

Note that I renamed `pImpl` into `Impl`, the `p` in the idiom is for pointer, the member in the containing class would be `Impl* pImpl;`.

Comment: Thank you very much. How to initialize values in the .cpp file and use them. Because in this way, this struct becomes a global struct in the cpp file. isn't it ?

Comment: @Zarco: That is the definition of a *type*, not an instance, and it is not at namespace level, but *nested* inside `AsynchronousFunction`. The constructor of `AsynchronousFunction` will need to allocate the object and provide the values needed inside the type, just as with any other member object.

Comment: In the constructor which has two parameters (fCall and param)
    m_pImpl = new Impl;
    m_pImpl->fCall = fCall; // comes from constructor as a parameter
    m_pImpl->m_hEvent = CreateEvent( NULL , true , false , NULL);
    m_pImpl->param = param; // comes from constructor as a parameter
    m_pImpl->returnVal = NULL;

Now I can access these struct values via m_pImpl pointer since it points to an object of Impl struct. Is this correct ?

Comment: I assume so, it depends on how you define the `struct`. Also, you can provide a constructor for the `Impl` type itself, and then the outer type just needs to `new` with the proper arguments.

Comment: Great. constructor for the Impl itself is really nice. thank you very much.